# Orchard cms works slowly

Tags: orchardcms

I have downloaded the newest version of orchard project from official repository at bitbucket in order to learn about it.
Unfortunately I have a performance issue. When I run the backend of Orchard CMS it works slowly.
Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Profile it to determine what module is slowing it down, and remove or fix it. The mini-profiler module is an easy way to profile. You can also enable the SysCache module.

Answer (score 0):

I'v solved the problem by installing Cache module.

http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Cache